# .NET 6: How to use method overloading in console app Startup?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-6.0

.NET 6 offers boilerplate-removal in console applications Startup class. I try to run this simple test code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

static void Test(int a, int b) { }

static void Test(int a, int b, int c) { }
```

I'm getting compiler error in the last line:

```
Error   CS0128  A local variable or function named 'Test' is already defined in this scope
```

My question is: How to use method overloading in boilerplate free Startup pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

static void Test(int a, int b) { }
```

is compiled to

```
[CompilerGenerated]
internal class Program
{
    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        static void Test(int a, int b)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You see that the method is a local method, ie declaring inside Main. You cannot have 2 local functions with the same name. THis also fails;

see https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/17275

```
namespace Foo {
    class Program {

      //  SerialPort port;  
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            static void Test(int a) { };
            static void Test(int a, int b) { };

    }
}
```

for the same reason. The new short Main syntax has an awful lot of limitations

Comment: So technically it should work, but it's .NET limitation for now?

Comment: @MichałGrzyśka: It's more "methods declared that way are effectively local methods, and local methods don't support overloading". Note that all of this is C# rather than .NET.

Comment: @JonSkeet but still it compiles wrongly IMO

Comment: @MichałGrzyśka: "Wrongly" would suggest that the compiler is violating the specification. I see no evidence of that. "It doesn't do what I want it to" isn't the same as "it compiles wrongly".

Answer (score 1):

You can still *create* a **class** and put all the methods you want to overload. That's what I did. It works fine even if you can add access modifiers because as [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71279381/16650576) said, the methods *after compilation* are in the **main method**

> ```
> [CompilerGenerated]
> internal class Program
> {
>   private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
>    {
>        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
>        static void Test(int a, int b)
>        {
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

so it's the same for access modifiers but hopefully the next version of .NET won't have this problem anymore but for now you can always *use a previous version* that keeps the "Main" method.